# Don't work calculation for matrix 1xm and nx1 in Python (Not NumPy)

Tags: python, matrix

I am new in Python. I have got such task:

> Write a program that receives a rectangular matrix as a sequence of
> rows as its input. The last line of the matrix is followed by a line
> containing only the string "end".
>
> The program should output a matrix of the same size, in which each
> element at position i, j is equal to the sum of the elements of the
> first matrix at positions (i-1, j), (i + 1, j), (i, j-1), (i , j + 1).
> For extreme characters, the adjacent element is on the opposite side
> of the matrix.
>
> In the case of one row / column, the element itself is a neighbor in
> the corresponding direction.

**For example**

Sample Input 1:

```
9 5 3
0 7 -1
-5 2 9
end
```

Sample Output 1:

```
3 21 22
10 6 19
20 16 -1
```

I wrote  code that work for rectangle and square matrices, but I do not know how to make it work on matrix 1 x m and n x 1.

```
l2 = []
l3 = []
length = 0
width = 0
while True:
    x = input()
    if x == 'end':
        break
    else:
        length = 0
        for i in x:
            if i.isdigit():
                length+=1
        l2.append(x)
        width+=1

for i in l2:
    l3.append(i.split(" "))
converted = [[int(i) for i in s] for s in l3]
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,length):
            if j==length-1:
                j = -1
            if i==width-1:
                i = -1
            print((converted[i-1][j]+converted[i][j-1])+(converted[i][j+1]+converted[i+1][j]), end = " ")
    print(end = "\n")
```

Also I can't use any classes, functions or libraries.

Somebody know how I can fix it ?

P.S. If someone will offer short code, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to handle both edges.  You're not quite doing that.  In particular, when width is 1, you'll set j = -1, and then you try to use j-1, which is out of range.

```
l2 = []
while True:
    x = input()
    if x == 'end':
        break
    l2.append( [int(k) for k in x.split()] )
width = len(l2)
length = len(l2[0])
converted = l2
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(length):
        im1 = (i-1)%width
        ip1 = (i+1)%width
        jm1 = (j-1)%length
        jp1 = (j+1)%length
        print((converted[im1][j]+converted[i][jm1])+(converted[i][jp1]+converted[ip1][j]), end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: As a side comment, you're setting 'width' to the number of rows, and 'length' to the length of each rows.  That's kind of backwards.  You might use "height' and 'width' for those.